# Swift 4 (BETA) merge dictionaries unable to infer type of parameter

Tags: swift, dictionary, merge, beta

I am using the exact sample code from Apple documentation in the header but I am getting this error: **Generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred** This is in the Swift 4 BETA WWDC release.

```
var dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

dictionary.merge(["a": 3, "c": 4])
       { (current, _) in current }
 // ["b": 2, "a": 1, "c": 4]

 // Taking the new value for key "a":
dictionary.merge(["a": 5, "d": 6])
       { (_, new) in new }
 // ["b": 2, "a": 5, "c": 4, "d": 6]
```

I tried assigning the dictionaries to variables and hard coding the types, but I still get the same error. Anyone else able to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the very responsive Swift developers I got a workaround right away after I tracked down the bug. https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4969

```
var dictionary = ["a": 1, "b": 2]

dictionary.merge(["a": 3, "c": 4].lazy.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }) { (current, _) in current }
// ["b": 2, "a": 1, "c": 4]

// Taking the new value for key "a":
dictionary.merge(["a": 5, "d": 6].lazy.map { ($0.key, $0.value) }) { (_, new) in new }
// ["b": 2, "a": 5, "c": 4, "d": 6]
```

Comment: It works for me without `lazy`, why is it better to include it?

Comment: you might check out this article, I think that avoids allocating memory for things that are not accessed, in this case, it looks like it would visit N nodes. https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-a-lazymapcollection-in-swift/

Comment: Oh, and by the way, this bug is fixed in the GitHub repo for Swift.

Comment: Thanks. This is the relevant passage from `LazySequenceProtocol` documentation comments: "Sequence operations taking closure arguments, such as `map` and `filter`, are normally eager: they use the closure immediately and return a new array.  Using the `lazy` property gives the standard library explicit permission to store the closure and the sequence
in the result, and defer computation until it is needed."

Comment: Thanks for finding that.